# 503 htaccess file only partially working

Tags: linux, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using the following as a 503 forwarder on a wordpress website. For some reason it words for foo.com/xyz, but not foo.com itself. Any thoughts?

**.htaccess file:**

```
ErrorDocument 503 /rdi/index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /rdi/index.php [R=503,L]
```

Comment: Why do you expect `http://example.com/` not to be translated to a valid directory? It's your document root!

Comment: In your haste to ridicule, you obviously didn't read the question properly. The root is NOT being translated, while everything else IS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any url that ends with a `/` requests a folder, and any url that does not end on a `/` requests a file. When you request `http://example.com`, you actually request `http://example.com/`, the document root of `example.com`. Your document root is obviously an existing folder, since otherwise you wouldn't be able to run a site at all.

You are using the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /rdi/index.php [R=503,L]
```

The second condition says: "If the requested filename is not a directory". Your document root **is** a directory, so that condition is false. It won't rewrite.

You can use the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /rdi/index.php [R=503,L]
```

What will this do? If you request `http://example.com`, the first condition will match, the second will be ignored because of the `[OR]` flag, and the third condition will be true. If you request `http://example.com/rdi/`, the first condition will be false and the second condition will be false and so the rule will not be used. If you request `http://example.com/asdfasdf/`, the first condition will be false, but due to the `[OR]` flag it will try the second condition, which is true. Then it checks the third condition which is true, which will then rewrite the request.